# Raycast does not go to target position

Tags: unity, raycasting

There is a part in my script where I need to make a raycast check from my gun's muzzle to the enemy. This enemy could be anywhere around player.

I found my ray is not connecting to the target position!

```
public Transform target, Bullet_position;

void Update {

  if (target != null)
  {
      RaycastHit hit;
      if (Physics.Raycast(Bullet_position.position, target.position, out hit, 500)            
      {
          Debug.DrawRay(Bullet_position.position, target.position, Color.blue, 500);

          if (hit.collider.tag == "enemy")
          {
              print(" In range and I can see you! ");
          }
          else
          {
              print(" None! ");
          }
       }
    }           
} // end update.
```

Comment: You know the second argument is a direction, not a position, right? Did you mean to use a linecast?

Comment: Yes, linecast is what I need for this script. Thank you DMG.

Comment: Note also that you should use the `CompareTag()` method instead of `.tag ==`

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in both of these methods is the *direction* you want the ray to travel, not the *position* you want it to reach. So when written like this...

`if (Physics.Raycast(Bullet_position.position, target.position, out hit, 500))`

`Debug.DrawRay(Bullet_position.position, target.position, Color.blue, 500);`

...you're asking for a ray along the line from:
`Bullet_position.position`
to:
 `Bullet_position.position + target.position`

If you prefer to specify two points, instead of a point and a direction, you can instead use the LineCast / DrawLine methods.